# breaking of query when passing a lot of elements in INOT IN caluse

Tags: sql

i am  bit unsure about the difference in execution of  two different sql queries  using NOT IN clause

first one is :

```
select employeeId from employee where employeeId not in (select  employeeId 
   from employee where employee.stream = 'Arts')
```

second is getting the results first of nested query then putting that result in query

example-

```
  select employeeId from employee where employeeId not in (1,12,30,45)
```

My question here is as there is limit on elements passed with IN and NOT IN clause.So would the query break in both cases if no of elements exceeded?

Comment: The 2nd query will be quicker than first, since in the first one, you need to first search for EmployeeID using the string criteria 'Arts'.  Never had an issue with a query breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most databases the limit for an IN clause is 1000. If that is an issue you could use the first query and avoid duplicates with a distinct clause.

```
select employeeId 
from employee 
where employeeId not in ( 
  select DISTINCT employeeId from employee where employee.stream = 'Arts');
```

Comment: What's the difference between your query and OP's query??  Nothing.

Comment: so if i use the first query then there is no chance of query breaking,right?

Answer (score 0):

No, there would go two execution one for `outer query` and other for `inner query`.

First your inner query get executed

```
select employeeId 
from employee 
where employee.stream = 'Arts';
```

Which produces  -> 1,12,30,45

Now the outer query get executed but with dependence of `inner query`

```
select employeeId 
from employee 
where employeeId not in (<inner query result>);
```

But if you care about performance then i would go with `not exists`

```
select e.*
from employee e
where not exists (select 1 
                  from employee e1 
                  where e1.employeeId = e.employeeId and 
                        e1.stream = 'Arts'
                 );
```